# How can I solve Question 8 of Edexcel IGCSE FPM Januray 2014 Paper 2?

Tags: vectors

[This is a question which i just can't seem to understand. For part (a) of question 8 the Mark Scheme (Answers) say 3**a**+3**e**](http://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/International%20GCSE/Further%20Pure%20Mathematics/2009/Exam%20materials/4PM0_02_que_20140123.pdf)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Edit your post to include what you have tried.

Comment: Also, you should be aware that it is considered rather rude to just post a link to a PDF and make users do a bunch of work to go find your actual question. You should type of the relevant parts of the question here and post a screenshot of the included diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $a$ is the "upwards" hypotenuse of a 30-60-90 right triangle, and $b$ is the same but downward facing. The horizontal distance traversed by $a$ (ignoring vertical displacement) is $OA/2$, same with $b$, and notice that the vertical components of $a$ and $b$ cancel each other. Therefore $a+b$ is a vector of length $OA$ in the horizontal-right direction. Since $\vec{AB}$ is a horizontal-right vector of length $2OA$, we have $\vec{AB}=2(a+b)=2a+2b$. (Thus I think the answer key is incorrect here.)